# Joining Data in Jekyll For Loop for One to Many

Tags: loops, for-loop, jekyll

With the following, assuming Brands, Models, Colors, and Items are separate data lists, where there is one **brand** -> many **models**, one **model** -> many **colors**, and so on, is it possible...

```
{% assign brand = site.data.brands %}
{% assign model = site.data.models %}
{% assign colors = site.data.colors %}
{% assign items = site.data.items %}
```

...to build a for loop with joined data such that I could create a table with a table header row containing the first **brand**, followed by a table sub-header row containing the first **model**, followed by a table sub-header row containing the first **color**, followed by a list of items that fit that color?

Right now I've accomplished this by ensuring that all of the data is in one data source, but it seems like joining the information would be more efficient down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the brand as an id to get its model, and the model id as the index of colors, etc, i.e, if `brand isn't an array, but a simple string:

```
{% assign brand = site.data.brands %}
{% assign model = site.data.models[brand] %}
{% assign colors = site.data.colors[model] %}
{% assign items = site.data.items[colors] %}
```